# Правильно ли я понимаю цель WSGI сервера?

Tags: django, gunicorn, wsgi

Возник вопрос - зачем нужно WSGI, что такое WSGI, WSGI сервер, WSGI приложение.
Нашел информацию и сформировал для себя следующие тезисы (ниже). Можете подсказать, правильно ли я по итогу всё понял?

WSGI - протокол, который описывает стандарт взаимодействия веб-приложения и веб-сервера (по факту WSGI сервера), так как нап

WSGI приложение - любое веб-приложение, которое может работать по протоколу WSGI.

WSGI сервер - application server, реализующий работу протокола WSGI (uwsgi/gunicorn)

Nginx общается с WSGI сервером по протоколу HTTP,  WSGI сервер общается с WSGI приложением по протоколу WSGI,  на WSGI сервере запущено само веб-приложение (запущено демоном) (ведь главное отличие WSGI от CGI в том, что приложение всегда запущено)  и каждый раз при запросе клиента WSGI веб сервер при помощи роутинга вызывает тот или иной обработчик из приложения.

Comment: Ну в целом всё так, только в WSGI нету роутинга, приложение реализует его само если хочет (или не реализует если не хочет)

Comment: Ну и раз уж у вас стоит метка Django, то имейте в виду, что он также [поддерживает ASGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/asgi/)

Comment: @andreymal да, роутинг осуществляется в самом веб приложении, неправильно подписал) про asgi тоже слышал, но подробно не знаю, нужно будет посмотреть,  спасибо огромнейшее!